# How do I fit my image into the container?

Tags: flutter, dart, mvvm, flutter-layout

I would like to get rid of the whitespace. The result currently is as below:
[image]

The white image is taking extra space and doesn't fit into the container.

Below is my code:

```
Container(
                 height: 180,
                 width: 160,
                 child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                    child: Image.network(book.pic == null ?
                'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3a/Book-icon-bible.png/900px-Book-icon-bible.png'
                :book.pic),
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: `Image.network( book.pic, fit: BoxFit.cover);`

Comment: Because width is fixed '160', I think that image can not stretch to height '180'.
I suggest using 'BoxFit.fitHeight'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fit: BoxFit.cover`. Also you don't need to use `ClipRRect` in this case, you can just use the container's own property to make the edges smoothed out like the example bellow.

```
Container(
    height: 180,
    width: 160,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
    ),
    child: Image.network(
    book.pic == null
        ? 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3a/Book-icon-bible.png/900px-Book-icon-bible.png'
        : book.pic,
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
),
```